# Error using iTextPDF and xhtmlrenderer, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfTemplate

Tags: java, pdf, itext, netbeans-8, xhtmlrenderer

I am testing ItexPDF with XHTMLRendered to parse a web to a pdf and got this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfTemplate
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:109)
org.docx4j.org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:103)
```

I am using iTextPDF 5.5.7 and xhtmlrendered.1.0.
  My code:

```
String File_To_Convert = "http://localhost:8080/index.php";   
 String url = new File(File_To_Convert).toURI().toURL().toString();
 System.out.println(""+url);
 String HTML_TO_PDF = "ConvertedFile.pdf";
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(HTML_TO_PDF); 
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(url);      
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);        
os.close();`
```

Comment: Rebuild your project, it seems `PdfTemplate` is not visible to itext.

Comment: Ive done it and failed:`class file for com.lowagie.text.DocumentException not found`

Comment: add the itexjar to the class path.

Comment: The iText-5.5.7.jar is in my classpath so are the extra jars in the version

Comment: You include the current iText (5.5.7) but your `xhtmlrendered` seems to require an ancient iText version (< 5)

Comment: O.o I didnt know that, so I have to downgrade to earlier versions of Itext then. thank you very muich, Ill try that

Comment: @Alexev You are using Flying Saucer, an unsupported product that *uses* an obsolete, unsupported version of iText. Flying Saucer isn't created by iText Group, nor endorsed by iText Group. Basically: if you see my name in the class path, you know that you're using ancient, unsupported software.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for your answer Bruno, I tried that one because was your recomendation at the book when the question was "parsing HTML to PDF" :(

Comment: You must have a mighty old book (2010) where I say *Usually you’ll get advice to use another product; for instance, xhtmlrenderer, aka Flying Saucer—a project that is built on top of iText.* That isn't a recommendation. That's what I noticed when reading answers back in 2009. When that book was written, XML Worker didn't exist yet.

Comment: o.O ok, I will be tryng XMLWorker then :) and find myself newer documentations :) All I have so far is the SO Q&A and the Itext in action 2dn edition 2011